# Clustering of multiple very similar time series

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning

so I have around 100 measurements of the current from a welding system. Each measurement has different sizes, but all are between 40k and 90k samples.

Some tests were done with very high (and different frequencies - 100, 200 hz) pulsed currents and others with continuous current.

What I am trying to do is compare them, or cluster them? or something? To detect the interesting features that differentiate them.

I was thinking of using first autoencoders to simplify every reading, and then use a Kmeans clustering. But this sounds to be a lot of work and some kind of work around. Then I found direct clustering of time series, would this make more sense?

I am definitely not an expert, some guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You may find the following thread useful:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323571/how-to-classify-m-multivariate-time-series-into-k-known-categories/323582#323582    Among other things, it talks about ways to preprocess a time series before feeding it to a machine learning method, be it classification, clustering or something else.